# How to create dynamic post_per_page using shortcode_atts - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Dear Wordpress Developers,

I create custom event management plugin using register_post_type functions.

The code like this:

```
function register_menu_page(){
    if(is_plugin_active('events/events.php')){
        register_post_type('event', array(
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt'),
            'has_archieve' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Events',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Event',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Event',
                'all_item' => 'All Events',
                'singular_name' => 'Event'
            ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt'
        ));
    }
}
```

and then, I'm display the event.

the code like this:

```
function displayEvents($atts){

        
    ob_start();

    ?>
    <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
    <?php 
 
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'post_per_page' => ''
    ), $atts);

    $homepageEvents = new WP_QUERY(array(
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['post_per_page'],
        'post_type' => 'event'
    ));

    while($homepageEvents->have_posts()){
        $homepageEvents->the_post();

        echo the_title();
        echo '<br />';

    }

    return ob_get_clean();

    } 

add_shortcode('displayEvents','displayEvents')
```

If I insert 'post_per_page' => '2', display 2 title.

I want it to be like [displayEvents post_per_page => '3'] to show 3 events, [displayEvents post_per_page => '4'] to show 4 events, and so on.

I know I need to use shortcode_atts(), but I try it out still not working.

All the answer is very appreciated, thank you very much!

Edited: I'm already solve my problem. The code above already working.

You can do this: [displayEvents post_per_page = '2' ] and show 2 event.

Comment: Please show your attempt using the `$atts` passed through the shortcode.

Comment: Hello @HowardE, I'm already solved my problem. I only did this:

$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'value' => ' '
), $atts);

and this:

  $homepageEvents = new WP_QUERY(array(
            'posts_per_page' => $atts['value'],
            'post_type' => 'event'
        ));

Comment: @HowardE maybe I'm panicked because of deadline and not thinking well yesterday. Thank you very much for your help